# Optimize GPU usage of tf.map_fn

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm building a neural network in tensorflow that works on 3D data and should predict positions of landmarks in the input data. The strategy is to densely (for each voxel) predict a category in a sphere with radius **r** around the actual landmark and also predict offset vectors that point to the actual location of the landmark. This strategy has been [proven](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08225) to be effective to refine landmark predictions.
Each pair of category probability and offset vector is a vote and I'm now trying to efficiently aggregate those votes in tensorflow.
For a input shape of (70,70,70) and 3 different landmarks plus the background class, I get two outputs out of my network:

- Probability tensor of shape(70,70,70,3+1)
- Offset vector tensor of shape (70,70,70,3*3)

I want to generate 3 output heatmaps of shape (70,70,70). Now for each voxel in the heatmap I need to aggregate the probabilities of the offset vectors that point to the voxel.
I tried to just use python and have 3 for loops, which takes 7 seconds on my CPU. This would be acceptable, but the final input shapes will be more like 300x300x300 and 3 for-loops would be O(N^3), so not feasible.
So I tried to pre-filter all irrelevant data using tensorflow and GPU acceleration. Irrelevant offset vectors are for example all these, that have a corresponding category probability under a certain threshold or that go out of bounds of the input shape. I implemented it with **tf.map_fn** like this:

```py
def filter_votes(probs, dists, prob_threshold, num_landmarks, sample_shape: tf.Tensor):
    f_sample_shape = tf.cast(sample_shape, tf.float32)
    probs = probs[:,:,:,1:] # probability of background is irrelevant
    indices = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(probs, prob_threshold)) # take only the indices of voxels, that have a category prediction over a certain threshold

    def get_flatvect(idx):
        f_idx    = tf.cast(idx, tf.float32)
        return tf.stack([
            f_idx[3], # this is the landmark number (goes from 0 to  2)
            probs[idx[0], idx[1], idx[2], idx[3]], # this is the predicted probability for the voxel to be the landmark
            f_idx[0] + dists[idx[0], idx[1], idx[2], idx[3]], # this is the x offset+ the actual x-position of the voxel
            f_idx[1] + dists[idx[0], idx[1], idx[2], idx[3]+3], # this is the y offset+ the actual y-position of the voxel
            f_idx[2] + dists[idx[0], idx[1], idx[2], idx[3]+6] # this is the z offset+ the actual z-position of the voxel
        ])
    res = tf.map_fn(get_flatvect, indices, dtype=tf.float32, parallel_iterations=6)

    def get_mask(idx):
        dist = idx[2:]
        return tf.reduce_all(tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(dist, 0.), tf.less(dist, f_sample_shape)))
    mask = tf.map_fn(get_mask, res, dtype=tf.bool, parallel_iterations=6) # get a mask that filters offsets that went out of bounds of the actual tensor shape
    res = tf.boolean_mask(res, mask)
    return res # I return a 2D-Tensor that contains along the 2nd axis [num_landmark, probability_value, x_pos, y_pos, z_pos]
```

And then I aggregate the filtered result in plain python, which is much faster due to radically less input data (most voxels have a low predicted categorical     probability).
The problem is even with input shapes (70,70,70), the filter operation only takes almost a minute with low GPU utilization. Even though I have 6 parallel iterations it is almost a factor of 10 slower than just aggregating everything in python. I tried researching **map_fn** and I read that it might not be possible for tf to place all operations on the GPU. But even then, I think it should be faster because:

- I have 6 parallel iterations and 6 CPU-Cores
- I do pre-filtering of relevant data with **tf.where** in the beginning and only iterate over the resulting indices instead of over all indices

So it seems like I'm lacking some basic understanding of what's going on. Maybe someone can clarify why my code is so inefficient?
Or maybe someone has a better Idea how to aggregate my votes in a vectorized manner?

Comment: I looks like you might be able to use `tf.gather_nd` for both of those python functions. Can you add comments to the code about the shapes of thensors, like you have for `res`? It makes things a little easier for people that aren't as familiar with your problem.

Comment: @McAngus thanks for looking into it! As it turns out your were right, tf.gather_nd should be used here. jdehesa submitted a neat solution below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize your function like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def filter_votes_vec(probs, dists, prob_threshold, num_landmarks, sample_shape: tf.Tensor):
    probs = probs[:, :, :, 1:]
    indices = tf.where(probs >= prob_threshold)
    landmark = tf.to_float(indices[:, 3])
    p = tf.gather_nd(probs, indices)
    indices_dists = tf.stack([
        indices,
        tf.concat([indices[..., :-1], indices[..., -1:] + 3], axis=-1),
        tf.concat([indices[..., :-1], indices[..., -1:] + 6], axis=-1)
    ], axis=1)
    d = tf.gather_nd(dists, indices_dists) + tf.to_float(indices[:, :3])
    res = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(landmark, 1), tf.expand_dims(p, 1), d], axis=1)
    mask = tf.reduce_all((d >= 0) & (d < tf.cast(sample_shape, tf.float32)), axis=1)
    res =  tf.boolean_mask(res, mask)
    return res
```

A quick test and benchmark with IPython:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    np.random.seed(100)
    probs = np.random.rand(70, 70, 70, 3 + 1).astype(np.float32)
    probs /= probs.sum(-1, keepdims=True)
    probs = tf.convert_to_tensor(probs, tf.float32)
    dists = tf.convert_to_tensor(100 * np.random.rand(70, 70, 70, 3 * 3), tf.float32)
    prob_threshold = tf.convert_to_tensor(0.5, tf.float32)
    num_landmarks = tf.convert_to_tensor(3, tf.int32)  # This is not actually used in the code
    sample_shape = tf.convert_to_tensor([50, 60, 70], tf.int32)

    result = filter_votes(probs, dists, prob_threshold, num_landmarks, sample_shape)
    result_vec = filter_votes_vec(probs, dists, prob_threshold, num_landmarks, sample_shape)
    value, value_vec = sess.run([result, result_vec])
    print(np.allclose(value, value_vec))
    # True
    %timeit sess.run(result)
    # CPU
    # 2.55 s ± 21.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
    # GPU
    # 54 s ± 596 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
    %timeit sess.run(result_vec)
    # CPU
    # 63.2 µs ± 781 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
    # GPU
    # 216 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Presumably, the ridiculous time for GPU is due to TensorFlow constantly exchanging data between the CPU and the GPU, which is a rather expensive.